# Golang - How to format GetTicker response to Luno API correctly?

Tags: go, formatting, response

I used the code example from this link https://github.com/luno/luno-go/blob/master/api.go
I used the ticker request portion and am trying to format the response to the fields.
eg log.Println("Ask: ", askPrice)

ctx := context.Background()

```
{
    req := luno.GetTickerRequest{Pair: "XBTZAR"}
    res, err := cl.GetTicker(ctx, &req)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
    log.Printf("%+v", res)      
    askPrice := res.Ask
    log.Println("Ask:", askPrice)
    time.Sleep(500 * time.Millisecond)
}
```

OUTPUT FOR log.Printf("%+v", res)
2022/03/22 06:56:39 &{Ask:657143.00000000 Bid:657071.00000000 LastTrade:657073.00000000 Pair:XBTZAR Rolling24HourVolume:181.37190600 Status:ACTIVE Timestamp:2022-03-22 06:56:34.98 +0200 SAST}

OUTPUT FOR log.Println("Ask:", askPrice)
2022/03/22 06:33:59 Ask: 658256.00000000

EXPECTED
Ask: 658256.00000000

How do I get rid of this bit in front of the value?
2022/03/22 06:33:59

Answer (score 0):

Dont use log.PrintXXX, use fmt package

Comment: Thank you Tiago Peczenyi. This answer was exactly what I needed!